# Prevent old form closing until new form opens

Tags: vb.net, winforms

A very basic/simple question with I'm sure, an even simpler answer, but I just cannot figure it out. I have two forms that a user can switch between using the corresponding menu link on each form. I want to be able to keep the previous form visible on screen until the new form is displayed. In it's current state, the form disappears off screen for around 3/4 of a second before the new one is shown and from a UI/design perspective, I'd like this to stay on screen.

I'm currently using the below code to close and open the forms:

```
form1.Show()
Me.Close()

form2.Show()
Me.Close
```

I have tried experimenting with `ShowDialog()` which does seem to keep it on screen on first run, but clicking back into the form a second time says an error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog.'

Is there a simple line of code to achieve what I want here?

Comment: Are form1 and form2 the default instances?

Comment: If you just want to switch between open forms by having only one of them displayed and you don't actually want to close the form (lose inputs, size, location, etc.), you could try calling `Me.Hide()` instead of `Me.Close()`.

Comment: Try this: `form1.Show() Task.Run(Async Function() Await Task.Delay(1000) BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() Me.Close())) End Function)`. `Me` should close 1 second after form1 is shown. You can also use a Timer.

Comment: @dbasnett Yes - this is a `Private Sub` in the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

If there is some time consuming code in the `Form.Load` event (for example, if data is being retrieved from a database) then the following code might help.

```
Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    'Assuming default instances
    Form1.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer incase there's an inherit reason this is not best practice or to avoid doing this, but using the below sped it up:

```
Private Sub menu1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menu1.Click
    form1.Show()
    form1.Refresh()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

This was inspired by adding in a `Application.DoEvents` working, so adjusted the code to avoid that dreaded line.